# How important is migration?

Tags: discussion, migration

I am most active on Biology and Cognitive Sciences and in Cognitive Sciences I quite often find questions that would fit Biology better. However, I understand that Psychologists (and in fact everyone) feel more comfortable sticking to their own circles.

1. How important is it to push for migration?
2. Is it an essential task for someone with a few k reputation like me to pursue these kinds of things? (Honestly, I'd rather not, but I feel a bit, erm, responsible to do so I guess :-)
3. and related - how do I flag for migration? Just flag it with a comment for moderator attention?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Migration is supposed to be reserved for truly excellent questions that are **off-topic** where asked, not just questions that would be **better** on another site.

If the question is of poor quality, then migrating it just forces another community to have to clean it up.

So to address your specific points:

> How important is it to push for migration?

Not very.  If it is a great question but is off-topic, then it is good to push for migration, but otherwise it may be better to leave a comment for the question author pointing him to the other site.  It is possible he isn't aware of the other site, or also possible he specifically picked the site he asked it on because he wanted an answer based on that community's expertise.  And you should probably refrain from commenting when the OP is very active both sites.  If they have an account and more than a small amount of reputation, then commenting is probably not necessary.  They should be familiar with what is on-topic and off-topic on each of the respective sites.

> Is it an essential task for someone with a few k reputation like me to pursue these kinds of things? (Honestly, I'd rather not, but I feel a bit, erm, responsible to do so I guess :-)

No, it is not an essential task.  Certain migrations can be done by 3K users (or the equivalent on Beta sites) but those are a limited number of possible sites.  And on Beta sites, you generally will not have any options other than the site's own meta site.  But open migration to any site not listed is a moderator-only function.

So you have to flag the post and ask that the moderator move the question.  There are other limits I'll mention below.

> and related - how do I flag for migration? Just flag it with a comment for moderator attention?

Depends.  As mentioned above, some sites do have migration paths to other related Stack Exchange sites.  But if the migration path is not listed, a moderator will have to move it, which means you have to flag the post, select other, and explain where you think the question should be moved.  It is also helpful to explain why.  A moderator is under no obligation to move the question however, they will only move it if they feel it is a good decision, which often includes consulting with moderators on the target site to make sure it is a good question for that site.

There are several things you need to take into consideration when making a decision whether a question should be migrated:

- Is the target site a Beta site?  Except in very exceptional cases, migration to Beta sites is discouraged and will almost always be declined.
- Is the question fairly new?  Migration is limited to questions that are younger than 60 days.  Older questions cannot be migrated, even by moderators.  It is technically feasible, but requires a developer to move the question.  This is only done in very special situations, such as the migration of questions from the old MSO (this site) to the new MSO.
- Do you understand the scope of the site you are suggesting migration too?  Don't just suggest a migration because you **think** it might be on-topic.  Suggest because you are experienced on the target site and you **know** it is on-topic.
- Is the question off-topic where asked?  Don't move questions around for the sake of moving questions.  It may be "better" on a specific site in your opinion, but there may also be reasons the OP choose to ask it where asked.  There is significant overlap between many Stack Exchange sites in which a question is on-topic in multiple places.